# Getting "Can't find xsubpp at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm" error when installing perl CPAN module

Tags: perl

Has anyone run into this issue? I am trying to install "Digest-SHA-5.93" from CPAN on linux and getting error

root@ns111 Digest-SHA-5.93]# perl Makefile.PL

Checking if your kit is complete...

Looks good

ExtUtils::MM_Unix::tool_xsubpp : Can't find xsubpp at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/ExtUtils/MM_Unix.pm line 3595.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind....i was able to fix it by installing perl-devel which updated my Extutils.

Thanks

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Can you please tell me how to install perl-devel? Not able to do it through cpan?